# Submitting a form to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

My form code is not generating correct HTML. Here's my code.

Here's the form code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "PropertyDetails", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div class="left">
            <label for="Name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" required name="Name" />

            <label for="Phone">Your Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" required name="Phone" />

            <label for="Email">Your Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="text" required name="Email" />
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <label for="Message">Your Message</label>
            <textarea name="Message"> 
            </textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here's my Controller. I have a breakpoint on the first line of the SendMail message which isn't being hit:

```
public class PropertyDetailsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendEmail(EmailData email)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // BREAKPOINT ON THIS LINE ISN'T BEING HIT
        {
```

etc.

Here's the class that should get populated with the form data and passed into the method (I'm not doing this myself. I assume it's happening automatically under the covers).

```
public class EmailData
{
    private string _name;
    private string _email;
    private string _phone;
    private string _message;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value == null ? string.Empty : value.Trim(); }
    }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(RegEx.Email, ErrorMessage = "Invalid e-mail address.")]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set { _email = value == null ? string.Empty : value.Trim(); }
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set { _phone = value == null ? string.Empty : HtmlHelper.StripIllegalXmlChars(value.Trim()); }
    }

    [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value == null ? string.Empty : HtmlHelper.StripIllegalXmlChars(value.Trim()); }
    }
}
```

Here's the HTML that's being generated:

```
<form action="" method="post">            
   <fieldset>
                <div class="left">
                    <label for="Name">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" required name="Name" />

                    <label for="Phone">Your Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" required name="Phone" />

                    <label for="Email">Your Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="text" required name="Email" />
                </div>

                <div class="right">
                    <label for="Message">Your Message</label>
                    <textarea name="Message"> 
                    </textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any ideas why the action is empty?

Comment: I'm attaching to the web process (w3wp.exe) from VS2010 and my breakpoint still isn't being hit in my SendMail method, even with the following code in my webpage:


@using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "PropertyDetails", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <fieldset>
        <div class="left">
            <label for="Name">Your Name</label>

etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using the code in the answers below, the generated html didn't have a value for action. I'm not sure why.

Comment: So can you change the question to show us your HTML now it's being generated by BeginForm  and show us how you get the HTML - is there a controller that produces that view?

Comment: Done. I've posted the current situation above.

Comment: Are you getting the HTML from a view? You know, using a controller to return a View that contains the HTML you've shown in your question? You need to do that, or the BeginForm syntax won't turn into the action that you need. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `<form>` declaration to this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "[Controller]")) { %>

<!-- Form data -->

<% } %>
```

Where `[Controller]` is the name of your Controller minus "Controller".  In other words, if the controller name is `HomeController`, you would use "Home".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action to your form

```
<form action="/SendEmail/" method="post">
```

But really this should be done using the MVC3 BeginForm helper.

You need to have your HTML rendered by a controller. So put your HTML in a View called "SendEmail" and write a controller action with an [HttpGet] attribute.
Call the Action "SendEmail" and in it just do `return View()`.

Like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SendEmail()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

That will cause the BeginForm to render the action="" properly.

Then once that's working you are going to have a problem when you do post the data back because the input fields aren't bound to you model. You need to add `@model yournamespace.EmailData` to the very top of your View and then you need to change your inputs to bind to the model properties.

I've no idea how good this link is but it's the first one I found that looks like it might guide you through a similar process http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2010/10/30/an-mvc-3-contact-form.aspx

Comment: The way birdus is using Html.BeginForm() will properly handle the form's Action attribute. If it's empty, it just means it's submitted to the same base url.

Comment: But he says the form is not submitting to his Post action, so his Get action can't be called SendEmail - no?

Comment: Html.BeginForm() will handle it properly. If it's outputting what he says, then yes, it is called SendMail. I think you are misunderstanding what he means when he says it's not submitting.

Comment: I am generating the HTML by returning the view:


return View("Property", _propertyDetails);

My team lead got the post back working, sort of. Looks like he just changed the name of the action to Property (same as the main action used when this page loads!). I guess they don't conflict simply because its decorated with [HttpPost]. Looks like what Andrew said is probably happening here. It's empty (action), so just submitting to the same base Url.

Anyway, now the problem is that the parameter (EmailData email) is coming through null. Ideas as to why this would happen?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It looks like it should bind to the EmailData OK. Perhaps you could try Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ and see what is really being posted when you press submit. Fiddler is free and easy to use and very useful for this kind of stuff.

Comment: When I look at TextView, SyntaxView, and WebForms tabs in Fiddler, there is nothing for the first page hit (i.e., no posted values). The form post does show my name/value pairs in those tabs. Beyond that, I'm not sure what this tells me. The email param is still null.

Comment: Just did some digging and found the following Exception in ModelState: "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Colliers.Sitecore.Web.Controllers.EmailData' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

Comment: Moreover, this works:         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Property(string name, string email, string phone, string message).
In other words, using individual params works, whereas using a class does not. Although less elegant, I'll use the individual params for now. Getting the job done is more important than perfection of execution.

Comment: Good - I know a lot of people will disagree but something working (even if it's a bit rough) is better than not something not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the form declaration within your view to this (using Razor syntax):

```
@using (this.Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "[your controller name]", FormMethod.Post))
{
  [form HTML]
}
```

The using statement will ensure that your form is closed correctly.

Also the `HtmlHelper.BeginForm` extension method is flexible enough that it generates the URI for the action based on the routes defined in your application's `RouteCollection`, such that if your routes change the form does not need to be updated; the change in URI is handled gracefully and automatically.